# Event Handlers for Dynamic Table Layout Panel in Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio, vba, button, dynamic, tablelayoutpanel

I am making a risk-type game for school that dynamically creates a 4x4 grid of buttons inside a table layout panel in visual basic.  I have successfully created the panel and buttons with names that correspond to the row and column of the button.  There are also two parallel arrays - one for button owner and the other for button number - that correspond to the owner of the button and the number of "armies" in the button.  My issue is that when the user clicks a certain button, I need to reference the button name/value to know how many "armies" the button has to control the "attack" portion of the player's turn.

The following code creates the table layout panel and the buttons with names.

```
'Create table Dynamically
    Dim ColCount As Integer = 4
    Dim RowCount As Integer = 4

    Dim f As New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 15)

    riskTable.AutoScroll = True
    riskTable.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
    riskTable.ColumnCount = ColCount
    riskTable.RowCount = RowCount
    For rowNo As Integer = 0 To riskTable.RowCount - 1
        For columnNo As Integer = 0 To riskTable.ColumnCount - 1
            Dim buttonname As String
            buttonname = "B" & rowNo & columnNo
            Dim button As Control = New Button
            button.Size = New Size(179, 100)
            button.Name = buttonname
            button.Text = "1"
            button.ForeColor = Color.White
            button.Font = f
            AddHandler button.Click, AddressOf buttonname_Click
            riskTable.Controls.Add(button, columnNo, rowNo)
        Next
    Next
    Me.Controls.Add(riskTable)
```

This is the dynamic event handler that I created.  I tried using 'Me.Click' to get the name of the button, but it only returns the name of the form.  I need to have code in here that references the name of the currently clicked button to then in turn reference the box owner and box number arrays.

```
Private Sub buttonname_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
    MessageBox.Show(Me.Name)
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I think that once I get this working, the rest of the game will be pretty simple to figure out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the name in 'button.Tag' instead/also:

```
button.Tag = buttonname
```

Then it is easy to get the name with:

```
Private Sub buttonname_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Click
     Dim result As String = CType(CType(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Button).Tag, String)
End Sub
```

(Check the *System.Windows.Forms.Button* though, might need some tweak to match your buttons inside the table. *riskTable.Controls.button* ?)

Comment: I ended up using the tag feature to keep track of the button owners.  Each button was dynamically assigned a tag of player1 or player2 so that each player had half of the buttons.  I was able to get rid of the arrays all together by just modifying the text property of the buttons to keep track of the "armies" in that button.  As far as the dynamic click events, I was able to make one event for all buttons by using the same code that I had above, but using "sender.name" which would refer to the button that was being clicked.